# View not visible until multitasking bar is opened - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I first got an auto layout crash when running on iPhone 3.5 inch display ios 5.1 - fixed that by turning off auto layout. BUT, now, when I run the app, the screen is black. The view is only visible when I double tap the home button to evoke the multitasking bar. Weird, right?

On app startup:

[image]

When evoking multitasking.

[image]

Code snippet:

```
   if(screenSize.height == 480) {
        // iPhone Classic
        welcomeViewController = [welcomeViewController initWithNibName:@"WelcomeViewController~iphone3.5" bundle:nil];
        viewController = [viewController initWithNibName:@"selectZone~iphone3.5" bundle:nil];
        fixtureViewController = [fixtureViewController initWithNibName:@"fixture~iphone3.5" bundle:nil];

        [windowOldiPhone addSubview:fixtureViewController.view]; 
        [windowOldiPhone addSubview:viewController.view];
        [windowOldiPhone addSubview:welcomeViewController.view];
        [windowOldiPhone makeKeyAndVisible];
        [windowOldiPhone bringSubviewToFront:welcomeViewController.view];
    }
```

NOTE: this doesn't happen on iPhone/iPad running iOS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `bringSubviewToFront` before calling `makeKeyAndVisible`. do like below

```
if(screenSize.height == 480) {
        // iPhone Classic
        welcomeViewController = [welcomeViewController initWithNibName:@"WelcomeViewController~iphone3.5" bundle:nil];
        viewController = [viewController initWithNibName:@"selectZone~iphone3.5" bundle:nil];
        fixtureViewController = [fixtureViewController initWithNibName:@"fixture~iphone3.5" bundle:nil];

        [windowOldiPhone addSubview:fixtureViewController.view]; 
        [windowOldiPhone addSubview:viewController.view];
        [windowOldiPhone addSubview:welcomeViewController.view];

        [windowOldiPhone bringSubviewToFront:welcomeViewController.view];
 [windowOldiPhone makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```